# script/generate problem with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard

I have this problem when I try to use "script/generate":

```
$ script/generate start
/Users/gst/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.1/lib/fast_xs.bundle: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10]
Abort trap
```

I am using Snow Leopard on my 32-bit MacBook Pro. Just installed it. 
I already tried to reinstall Ruby with MacPort but somehow it still doesn't work.

I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks, Gerald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
sudo gem update
it looks like a problem with your hpicot gem, so you could also do gem remove hpricot to fix it. The update might update it to a newer version without this problem.

Comment: I did that, but now I am getting this:

$ script/generate start
Couldn't find 'start' generator

Comment: $ script/generate start
Couldn't find 'start' generator